# Creating a DSL: How to load a clojure file in the current context

Tags: clojure, dsl

I am trying to create a DSL for packaging software using clojure. I want to define macros, functions, etc. and then load a file, and I want all of those things I define to be in the same namespace as the file itself, so that if I define a macro `abe`, I can use it in the file without using `abe`'s fully qualified name.

I have this so far:

```
(binding [*ns* (find-ns 'my-namespace)]
    (load-file "Myfile"))
```

But I get the feeling I'm doing it wrong.

Also, it would be nice to even have locally bound variables accessible within the clojure file. Something like this:

```
(let [a 1]
    (binding [*ns* (find-ns 'my-namespace)]
        (load-file "myfile")))
```

Where `a` is usable from within `myfile`.

The idea is to allow a programmer to specify how to package something in real clojure, but with the language extended in ways that are transparent to the programmer.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there some better "idiomatic" way of creating a DSL in clojure?

Comment: Doesn't a regular `:use` work (without prefix)?

Comment: @christophe-de-troyer The programmer of the loaded file would have to use `:use`, but I want the file to transparently include the namespace. The programmer shouldn't have to know what to `:use`, it should just be there, at least that's what I'm going for.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without any explicit code. But I'm no Clojure wizard either.

Comment: Riemann has a similar goal, take a look at how they do it.